# how to Show two creatives simultaneously with DFP Google admanager

Tags: ads, google-ad-manager

I want to show two creatives always simultaneously on two placements on my page using google admanager. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this issue, and as no one has answered yet I think i should answer My own question then.

you can show two creatives together every time using admanager by setting the display creatives property to as many as possible and making sure that no other line item is in any way of higher priority than this one, in this case the creatives will be shown together.

A detailed solution can be found here [display-two-creatives-simultaneously-dfp-admanager](http://umairj.com/236/display-two-creatives-simultaneously-dfp-admanager/)